# Where are meteor's installed packages located?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteorite

I installed twitter bootstrap using `meteor add bootstrap`. I want to look at the bootstrap css files, but I can't find them anywhere.

I have looked in my application folder, and I've looked at many folders in the .meteor folder.
In `app-name/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages` I came across bootstrap.min.js, but no bootstrap.min.css anywhere.

There's nothing in my `app-name/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/packages` folder.

Does anybody know where the bootstrap css file(s) is located?

Edit: I looked in my generated html page, and found `<link href="/c06ffbf557927aa81d97be1421cb5a36cd8fd88f.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>`

I found that file in `app-name/.meteor/local/build/programs/client/c06ffbf557927aa81d97be1421cb5a36cd8fd88f.css`. It is bootstrap, but *why* is it called that random string, and not bootstrap.css? Is this a bootstrap only problem, or do other packages have this too?

Comment: The local build files are the minified versions.  See my answer below :)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Typically they are in your home folder in the .meteor directory:

```
/home/username/.meteor/packages.
```

If you are usining meteorite packages as well, they find their way to

```
/home/username/.meteorite/packages.
```

They are symlinked into individual projects with the 'meteor add' action to avoid having to have a version of every package installed for every project you run.

Comment: When I go into /home/username/.meteor/packages, I can see folders with all the packages I installed but these folders don't seem to include the code of the packages. Just some metadata. Do you know where I can find the code of the packages? Thanks!

Comment: For Foundation 6, I found code at /home/user/.meteor/packages/zurb_foundation-sites/6.1.2/web.browser/dist/foundation.js

Comment: The file structure is a bit of a moving target and varies by Meteor version.  Since the 1.0 it has seemed pretty stable.

Answer (score 16):

For Windows it's at

```
C:\Users\[YourUser]\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\
```

Answer (score 7):

For mac users they are located in:

```
User/.meteor/packages
```

Via Terminal:

```
cd ~/.meteor/packages
```

Via Finder, press CMD + Shift + G and enter:

```
~/.meteor/packages
```

I also wrote about it here:
https://medium.com/@geneparcellano/where-are-meteor-js-packages-installed-f9e123e67f76#.8rgrd8nwj